# group and fill in geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to do this plot

[image]

My understanding is that i need to use fill for model names `name` (base vs mother) and group for Year.

I tried

```
test%>%ggplot(aes(as_factor(sector), value, fill=name, group=factor(YEAR)))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.5)
```

but it does not work...

[image]

How to fix this? :(

my data looks like this

```
structure(list(value = c(45.7835023085923, 46.727175387221, 47.6992761579977, 
48.0597275867616, 50.7882757046681, 50.8768402521772, 42.7273124207896, 
43.9851413648616, 47.5599896653421, 47.8361505231604, 51.0693121296854, 
51.2675797116211, 45.0282059530599, 46.0840505213407), name = c("value_add_base_sector_total", 
"value_add_mother_sector_total", "value_add_base_sector_total", 
"value_add_mother_sector_total", "value_add_base_sector_total", 
"value_add_mother_sector_total", "value_add_base_sector_total", 
"value_add_mother_sector_total", "value_add_base_sector_total", 
"value_add_mother_sector_total", "value_add_base_sector_total", 
"value_add_mother_sector_total", "value_add_base_sector_total", 
"value_add_mother_sector_total"), YEAR = c(2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2021, 
2021), sector = c("Catholic", "Catholic", "Government", "Government", 
"Independent", "Independent", "Catholic", "Catholic", "Government", 
"Government", "Independent", "Independent", "Catholic", "Catholic"
)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```r
ggplot(df, aes(factor(YEAR), value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), width = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(.~sector, switch = 'x') +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c('#bebebe', '#1e3763')) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(face = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: amazing!!! thank you so much!!! very belated, but your answer helped me so much!

Answer (score 0):

like so?

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = as.factor(YEAR), y = value, fill = as.factor(YEAR))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~sector, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree faceting might be helpful here, unless, do you need it to look exactly the same (no facets?).   Otherwise I'd use facet.grid and move the strips to the bottom of the graph. I added a negative value so make it appear more similar and you can play with the theme to change the styles...

## Adding negative value and changing "name"

```
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(value=ifelse(name=="value_add_mother_sector_total"&YEAR=="2016"&sector=="Catholic", -40, value)) %>% mutate(name=ifelse(name=="value_add_mother_sector_total", "MLSH", "Base"))
```

## Plot

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=YEAR , y=value, fill=name)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", color="black", width=1) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size=.5)+ labs(x=NULL, y= "Value")+ scale_fill_manual(name=NULL, values=c("Base"="navy","MLSH"= "gray80"))  + theme(panel.border = element_rect(size = 1, color="black",fill=NA))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20)) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 22, face="bold", vjust=-.5),axis.title.y = element_text(size = 22, face="bold", vjust = -1.5)) + facet_wrap(~sector,strip.position="bottom") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2011, 2016, 2021)) +theme_calc() + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-45, 55),breaks = seq(-45, 55, 5))+ theme(legend.position = "bottom")+ theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),axis.title=element_text(size=16, face="bold"), strip.text = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),strip.placement = "outside",panel.grid = element_line(colour="gray90")) +  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa4yN.jpg)